# How to get function name passed as parameter for callback purpose using Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have following sample of code to get the function name which is passed in parameter for callback purpose.

```
var operation = {
    display : function(fun) {
        console.log('operation "'+ fun.toString() +'" performing' );
        //here i am getting
        /*operation "function () { 
                console.log('operation "subtraction" performed' ); }" performing
        */
        // **instead of entire function i would like to get only method name**
        fun.call();
    },
    addition : function() {
        console.log('operation "addition" performed' );
    },
    subtraction : function() {
        console.log('operation "subtraction" performed' );
    },
    multiplication : function() {
        console.log('operation "multiplication" performed' );
    }
}
operation.display(operation.subtraction);
//Output should be
// operation "subtraction" performing
// operation "subtraction" performed
operation.display(operation.multiplication);
//Output should be
// operation "multiplication" performing
// operation "multiplication" performed
operation.display(operation.addition);
//Output should be
// operation "addition" performing
// operation "addition" performed
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What is the question? Remove the irrelevant parts of the code and format it, that helps too.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions are anonymous; i.e. they are **nameless** function expressions. Before you can get their names, you have to give them names.

```
var o = {
    foo: function bar() {} // named function expression, name is "bar"
};
function getName(fn) {
    return fn.name;
}
getName(o.foo); // "bar"
```

The functions, however, do have related keys in your `operation` *Object*, but you can not find out which *key* of an *Object* something was for certain, code to find a match would be a guess because values don't have to be unique.

```
function guessKey(val, obj) {
    var key;
    for (key in obj)
        if (obj[key] === val)
            return key;
    return null;
}
guessKey(o.foo, o); // "foo"
```

---

`Function.prototype.name` shim for IE9+ (maybe also 8; not sure)

```
if (Function.prototype.name === undefined) { // may be "" so can't use !
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "name", {
        get: function () {
                var s = Function.prototype.toString.call(this);
                return s.slice(9, s.indexOf('('));
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the function object contains the "name" property returning the name of the method

**UPDATE**
AS IE does not implement the name property for functions use a RegEx ;) This little function can help you out:

```
function getFnName(fn) {
  var f = typeof fn == 'function';
  var s = f && ((fn.name && ['', fn.name]) || fn.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/));
  return (!f && 'not a function') || (s && s[1] || 'anonymous');
}
```

Seen here: https://gist.github.com/dfkaye/6384439

Comment: `name` does not work in this situation, as the function passed was defined as an anonymous function. It will simply return `""`, instead of the name of the property on which it was defined. Also, `name` is not available in any version of IE, including IE11.

Comment: This still unfortunately does not show the property name for anonymous functions (it returns `"anonymous"`), but that's not easy to solve without a change in the approach.

Comment: Make a suggestion pls and I'll catch your thoughts ;)

Comment: As I said, it isn't easy to solve with the code as it is :) I've removed my downvote.

Comment: very kind :) Paul S. approach is a good one as it acts like a polyfill.